# Gauke terminal + powerline: config confusion and parameter issues

Tags: terminal

When trying to edit `powerline` for my `bash` shell, guake terminal on Ubuntu 14.10, I attempted to copy and edit the default configuration, to no avail. After some experimentation I realised none of the files in my `.config` could be the loaded configuration. However, when I booted up today I was met with errors, and it seems to be working now and sourcing my custom theme. I say custom, but its barely been changed from default. Now I am met with the problem of editing the theme.

I have looked up the documentation "https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/segments/common.html" and I have added the line:

```
powerline.segments.common.vcs.branch(ignore_statuses=(), status_colors=True)
```

But instead of changing the behaviour of `powerline`, I am met with errors. Is this not the appropriate syntax?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please take a deep breath and slow down. Now [edit your post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/199505/edit) to provide some details that may help us be able to help you.

Comment: Please list the error messages. If they relate to more than one line please also provide a few lines above and below the single(?) line that you changed in the configuration.

Comment: Ah. The documentation does include that line you've added, but in the documentation it declares the _structure_ of the line, not an example. You need to replace the parameters with the values you want to use. For example `powerline.segments.common.vcs.branch(["u"], True)`

Comment: That makes sense, but this line doesn't work either, I get a ValueError: expecting delimter ',' at line 17 col 57.

Comment: Post the error messages in your Question

Answer (score 1):

In my distribution, Arch Linux, the default powerline configuration files resides `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/powerline/config_files`. When a file is not present in your `.config/powerline` directory, the equally named one found there is used instead.

This structure provides a useful way to start tweaking your powerline configuration.

1. Copy all the default files from `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/powerline/config_files` to `~.config/powerline`,
2. edit them to your liking,
3. check their validity by running `powerline-lint`,
4. repeat (2) until satisfied and lastly
5. delete the files you did not modify.